# Can't access SSH after run iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have EC2 instance and I tried to block all outgoing connection using :

```
iptables -P OUTPUT  DROP
```

But now I can't connect to that server again. I tried from AWS web console, but still can't connect.

How can I connect to it?

Comment: Have a look at `iptables-apply` next time, that'll save you some trouble.

Comment: This command drops all IP packets sent from the server, which means that incoming SSH connection packets arrive fine, but any replies to the packets are dropped by the firewall. You need to do connection tracking based firewall rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart it from the console. If you only did the iptables command from the shell prompt it’s not permanent.

Comment: thank you, worked, actually I did it before you answer my question :)